# Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. - Magento Migration

Tags: migration, magento2.3, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

I'm migrating from Magento 1.9.3.3 CE to Magento 2.3.0 EE, I'm facing the below error.

> Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=5859 in vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/ResourceModel/Adapter/Mysql.php on line 173

I have increased `max_allowed_packet` to `1G` and `wait_timeout` to `28800` after that also it does not works, it throws the same error.

any help would be much appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please try below changes in `config.xml` file at location `magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-commerce/1.9.3.3`. I have faced same issue and below changes fixed my issue.

```
<bulk_size>100</bulk_size>
<direct_document_copy>1</direct_document_copy>
```

Comment: Working great !!!! thanks

Comment: Amazing! Save my day